# Migrating Windows 7 to SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd, migration

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Changing hard disk with ssd, can I migrate contents so that I can switch drives without a hassle?](https://superuser.com/questions/134915/changing-hard-disk-with-ssd-can-i-migrate-contents-so-that-i-can-switch-drives-w)
>   [Replacing notebook SATA hard disk with SSD without reinstalling](https://superuser.com/questions/137868/replacing-notebook-sata-hard-disk-with-ssd-without-reinstalling)

Hi, I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise x64. I just bought an Intel X25-M SATA SSD drive and I would like to run Windows 7 from that drive.

I'm on a Dell T5500. Any help / links would be appreciated.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/137868/replacing-notebook-sata-with-ssd-without-reinstalling or http://superuser.com/questions/134915/changing-hard-disk-with-ssd-can-i-migrate-contents or others.

Comment: also related/useful: http://superuser.com/questions/74896/confirming-that-windows-7-is-using-ssd-optimizations http://superuser.com/questions/45988/any-solid-state-drive-ssd-compatibility-issues-concerns-with-dell-d820-d830 and http://superuser.com/questions/47121/upgrade-to-ssd-drive